# Browser redirects non existing images

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a very strange problem. I have a folder on my webserver with one image in it named 1.jpg

When I want to call www.mydomain.com/folder/3.jpg in any browser it redirects automatically to www.mydomain/folder/1.jpg.
When I try another name like www.mydomain/folder/test.jpg it returns 404 like it should.

The problem is I want to check if the image exists and then display it (fileexists() in a php page).
But even so the image doesn't exist it always returns true and displays 1.jpg.

I also looked at the htaccess and even cleared the whole htaccess but I didn't change. I have no idea what is going on.

**EDIT**

I have one htaccess in the folder with

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "restricted area"  
AuthUserFile /.htpasswd  
require valid-user
Allow from www.mydomain.com
Satisfy Any
```

and on in the root folder with

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: can you provide relevant code for php and/or htaccess? hard to be-dug it otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*)\.(jpg|png) test.php
```

I tested this with my .htaccess and it always redirected to test.php if the image doesn't exists.

Comment: Seems to work now. Thanks very much. Even though I still do not understand why that happened.